# CosmosDB create unique document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Currently, I'm using CosmosDB with SQL API in C#. Right now when it creates a new event in the Event collection, it needs to create a document in the EventData collection that has the same id, eventid and origin. Then it needs to set the count to 1. If the document already exists in Event collection, it throws an error that the eventid is unique and it needs to update the corresponding count in EventData. I set the partition key to the /origin and the unique key to /eventid. This is what I have come up with but not getting what I need with anything I try:

Data coming into Event:

```
{
    "id": randomly generated from cosmosdb,
    "eventid": "1234",
    "origin": "5.6.7.8"
}
```

What it needs to make in EventData:

```
{
    "id": same as the id from the Event collection,
    "eventid": "1234",
    "origin": "5.6.7.8",
    "count": 1
}
```

Then when an event comes in and has the event id "1234" it will find that it is already in the Event collection and increment the corresponding document in EventData:

```
{
    "id": same as the id from the Event collection,
    "eventid": "1234",
    "origin": "5.6.7.8",
    "count": 2
}
```

Azure Function:

```
public static async Task CreateEventAndUpdateCountAsync(string database, string eventCollection, string eventDataCollection, string input){
    MyClass myClass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(input);
    try
    {
        //try to create a document, if not catch error
        //create document in Event collection, and if no error create a document with the count of 1

        await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(database, eventCollection), myClass, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(myClass.origin) });
        Count count = new Count();
        count.eventid = myClass.eventid;
        count.origin = myClass.origin;
        await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(database, eventDataCollection), count, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(myClass.origin) });
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException de)
    {
        if (de.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
        {
            // had it trying to read the document and do a ReplaceDocumentAsync
            // need to find the document in the EventData Collection with the same eventid as myClass and increase count by 1               
        }


        else
        {
            log.Info(de.ToString());
            throw;
        }        

    }
}

public class myClass {
    public string eventid { get; set; }
    public string origin { get; set; }
}

public class Count {
    public string eventid { get; set; }
    public string origin { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: this sounds too relational for cosmos db. question is, is there a real reason why you need to have `Events` and `EventData` in separate collections?

Comment: High volume of events being created and destroyed alongside the count being updated frequently (milliseconds) to where it would cause issues and possible dupes.

Comment: 1. you cannot do transactional operations across collections so you've already given up consistency (dupes) there. 2. your documents are almost identical across collections so i don't see benefit of multiple collections. Why wouldn't you put both documents into same collection, give them property `type= Event | EventData` & same partition key. then leave `EventData` to have whatever `id` it needs and give it relational field like `eventId`. Then have stored procedure (or trigger) that would insert into `EventData` based on what it finds `Event`.

Comment: Important is, in that setup you would keep your docs within transactional boundaries (partition key). Other than that, you could consider using Cosmos DB Change Feed + Azure Functions.

Comment: So should I add and increment the count to the Event collection? Or do that within a stored procedure and still put it in EventData?

Comment: that's not a trivial question. it highly depends on the type of your load (read vs. write) & docs size. if all your docs contain is what you've shown above, i would definitely start with keeping everything in single `Event` collection and update count there directly. then if you see bottlenecks, hot-spots, too high cots, etc....then i would think abuot optimizations by splitting documents into different types (using `type` field) but most probably never introduce separate collection (unless i would use Change Feed & Functions).

Comment: You're probably right but people above me are concerned about any possible collisions that could happen or dupes. This is storing some critical network data.

Comment: that is the reason more not to go with cross-collection solution. in that case you must find data model where your events&eventdata fall into same partition key as that is the transaction boundary.

Comment: good starting point is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#partitioning-and-loggingtime-series-data

Comment: We're using the origin (ip address/hostname) for the partition

Comment: There's really no avoiding checking for existence first, if you plan on updating the document (or writing a new one). Alternatively, you could simply write a new document (without any count), and then periodically (or on-demand) compute the count by querying the count of all events for a given origin (and optionally writing the result to a summary-count document). Also, by doing out-of-band count computation, you avoid any type of conflicting (or serialized) count-updates if you have, say, multiple threads consuming events for the same origin simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The CosmosDB SDK supports the `Upsert` method. This method will create if something is missing and update if it exists.

You can change your second `CreateDocumentAsync` call to this:

`await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(database, eventDataCollection), count, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(myClass.origin) });`

Comment: If I do this, how can I increment the count? Won't this just keep it as 1? And if the document already exists, it will throw unique key error.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Why don't you do a ReadDocumentAsync instead and handle that if it exists?

Comment: Tried it both ways. If I read the document and it exists, I have to get the id. I'm guessing I need to write a query?

Comment: Yeah you'd have to go with a partition specific query.